# How to localize server data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter App with Firestore as a backend for storing dynamic data shown in the app. I am adding localization support for multiple languages using the `flutter_localizations` library as mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#an-alternative-class-for-the-apps-localized-resources).

My server data is loaded from Firestore and saved in a sqlite database. The data is loaded to class object and shown in a Flutter widget.

How do I restructure my class models, database and logic to show correct string based on app locale?

What I came up with so far:

Firestore:

```
- songs (collection)
  -- QWSAWERFCUT (id)
     -- title: Smells Like Teen Spirit
     -- title_hi: स्मेल्स लाइक टीन स्पिरिट
     -- title_mr: स्मेल्स लाइक टीन स्पिरिट
     -- ....
```

Sqflite database:

```
db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE $activityTable("
        "$colId TEXT PRIMARY KEY , " 
        "$colTitle TEXT, "
        "$colTitle_hi TEXT, "
        "$colTitle_mr TEXT, "
        ....
)
```

Dart Class:

```
class Activity {
  String id;

  String title;
  String title_hi;
  String title_mr;
  ...

  // Function to get locale-specific data for each field

  String getTitle(Locale locale){
    if(locale==Locale('hi')) {
      return title_hi;
    }
    else if(locale==Locale('mr')) {
      return title_mr;
    }
    else{
      return title;
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to add each field in multiple languages to my Firestore, Database, class object and special function for each field to get locale-specific data, or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add one column to every table to identify which local is used for each row entries. When you request data from client device via API call, pass the required local name, eg: en.

Note: Take one local, say 'en' as default local so that you can use this as a fallback local.